# Using python property and still able to set the values explicitliy

Tags: python

Im trying to understand how the @property decorator works.

Here I have used method y as a property for field x,

After the attribute-self.x has a property, does it mean that we can't set the value explicitly..

I thought  the last statement--> c.x = 2 will not work once you have the property method set on a variable?

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.list = [1,2,3,4,10]
    @property
    def y(self):
        print 'getting'
        self.x = sum(self.list) 
        return self.x

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        print 'setting'
        self.x = value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
    print 'Value of c.y=',c.y
    print '-'*80
    c.y = 50
    print '-'*80
    print c.y
    print '-'*80
    if c.y >5:
        print 'Hi'
```

Comment: Sorry, which line are you referring to?

Comment: I don't see a `c.x = 2` anywhere. What output do you get from your script, and what output do you expect?

Comment: You may be better off doing explicit property creation as in `y = property(_get_y, _set_y)` if the behaviour here confuses you, since the two forms are strictly equivalent. y is just a class attribute of type `property` and has no control over the independent behaviour of `self.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is limited support for [private instance variables](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) in Python via name-mangling

to avoid exposing `x`, you need two leading underscores, i.e. `__x`

Comment: Isn't the convention to use a single underscore to indicate to users that altering the value is unsupported, and if they do it anyway, they do so at their own risk?

Comment: @jpmc26, true. However, as indicated in the link the double underscore brings additional protection by way of name-mangling into play

Comment: Yes, it does, but the impression I always got was that the name mangling feature was against the grain, so to speak, in the Python culture. That is, Python enthusiasts would encourage that a single underscore be used and it be left to the user to use this code wisely. "We're all adults here" and all that. Not to mention that the name mangling doesn't help if someone calls `dir` on an instance of your class.

Comment: @jpmc26, you are probably right, the predominant use case for name-mangling is associated with avoiding clashes with names defined by subclasses

Answer (score 3):

You can always set x explicitly.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.lst = [1,2,3]

    @property
    def y(self):
        self.x = sum(self.lst)
        return self.x

    @y.setter
    def y(self,value):
        self.x = value


f = Foo()
print f.y #6
print f.x #6
f.x = 3
print f.x #3
print f.y #6
print f.x #6
```

The problem is that in this example, calling the getter (`y`) also *sets* the value of the `x` attribute, so you'll never see the change of `x` if you're doing all of the changing via `y` because the act of looking at `y` changes the value of `x`.

One way that you might try to get around that limitation is:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.lst = [1,2,3]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return sum(self.lst) if self.x is None else self.x

    @y.setter
    def y(self,value):
        self.x = value
```

Now if you explicitly set a value for `x` (or `y`), that value will stick until you set it back to `None` which you could even do in another function decorated with `@y.deleter` if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You cant prohibit to change attribute directly using property decorator but You can do such a trick I think

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__dict__['x']
    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.__dict__['x']=value
```

this will allow You to implement behavior like You have described

Comment: Why use `self.__dict__['x']` when you could just do `self.x`?

Comment: After you have make x property with setter each time one will try to set it via self.x `
 @x.setter
 def x(self, value):` will be run so in this case this function will be called recursevely

Comment: Ahh ... I didn't notice that `x` was also the name of the property.  Sorry, I didn't read closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not provide any capability for preventing callers from accessing variables. In other words, there is no "private" in Python. By convention, a variable or method prefixed with an underscore is not intended for external use. E.g.,

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
        self.list = [1,2,3,4,10]
.
.
.
```

I can still access `_x` if I really want to, and nothing prevents me from setting it.

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c._x
10
>>> c._x = 20
>>> c._x
20
```

However, by **convention**, the underscore tells me I'm doing something dangerous and ill advised. It's up to me, the programmer, to determine if I broke anything by doing it.

This is a conscious design decision made when creating Python. The idea is that whoever uses your class is responsible for what they do with it; if they misuse it and it breaks, that's their fault. You warned them with the underscore. I think the notion that a clever programmer can get around your attempts to lock them out anyway may have played a role in the decision (such as reflection libraries or interacting with the compiled bytecode directly), but don't hold me to that.

On a mildly related note, the underscore does actually do something if the variable (including other imported modules, functions, etc.) is a member of a module. Members beginning with an underscore are not imported by `import *`. E.g.,

a.py

```
_a = 10
b = 50
```

Command prompt:

```
>>> from a import *
>>> b
50
>>> _a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_a' is not defined
```

In your particular example, `x` and its setter are relatively useless since you're overriding its value any time the getter is called.

Answer (score -4):

class Foo(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.x = None
        self.lst = [1,2,3]

```
@property
def y(self):
    return sum(self.lst) if self.x is None else self.x

@y.setter
def y(self,value):
    self.x = value
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?